# Populate A Function Handle "Array" in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, nested-loops, function-handle

I have the following function handle uppercase K and array of lowercase k and gamma values.

```
N = 3;
k = randi([1,1000],N+1,1,"double");
gamma =  randi([1,100],N+1,1,"double");

K = @(x) [zeros(N,N)];
```

I need to populate this function handle with specific values of lowercase k and x. For this example with N=3, the corresponding uppercase K matrix is:
[image]

Looking at this uppercase K matrix, one can see that the pattern is to start with the first two elements in the matrix in green, copy their values, shift them to the right once, shift them down once, and increase the index of each variable in the elements by 1.

I would like to return uppercase K using the following function:

```
function K = karray (k,N)
    K = @(x) [zeros(N,N)];
    for i=1:1:N
        for j=1:1:N
            K(i,j) = (k(i)*gamma(i)+k(i+1)*gamma(i+1))*x(i)^2+k(i)+k(i+1);
            K(i,j+1) = -3*k(i+1)*gamma(i+1)*x(i)^2-k(i+1);
        end
    end
end
```

My initial thought was to use a nested for loop to populate uppercase K, but since K is a function handle, I can't simply access each element in K by using `K(i,j)`. I think that my method for populating K is correct, but I'm not sure how to properly access each element in K.

Comment: What is `x` here?

Comment: As I commented to your other post, the difficulty has nothing to do with `K` being a handle, it is that you’re trying to do everything in an anonymous function. You can create a regular named function, and get the handle to that. In a named function you can use loops and anything else you might need.

Comment: Also, I’m confused by your example. The code doesn’t produce the zeros in the equation, and each loop iteration of `j` overwrites a result from the previous iteration. That cannot be right.

Comment: @rahnema1 x is just a variable that represents the displacement of masses in a mass-spring-damper system. This K matrix ends up getting passed to MATLAB’s ODE45 function to solve for the displacement of each mass x(1), x(2), x(3), etc.

Comment: @CrisLuengo. You are right, I forgot to include the zeros on the off diagonal of K. As N increases above 3, the off diagonal should be populated with the proportionate amount of zeros. The pattern only occurs along the diagonal. Regarding the overwriting, is it because my nested for loop isn’t written correctly? Is my karrray function not a regular named function? I guess I’m still not sure what you mean by regular named.

Comment: @JonathanFrutschy So if I correctly understand `x` is a vector not a scalar nor a function handle?

Comment: Yes, `karrray` is a named function. But inside you create an anonymous function `K` to return. Instead return the handle to a named function, as in the answer below.

Comment: @rahnema1 Yes, x is a vector composed of [x(1),x(2), … , x(N)].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here [spdiags](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) is used to create the diagonal matrix. Otherwise you may use for loops to fill the diagonal matrix.

```
function K = karray(k, gamma, N)
    K = @(x) make_diagonal(x, k, gamma, N);
end

function out = make_diagonal(x, k, gamma, N)
    x = x(:);
    x = [x(1:N); 0];

    ck = circshift(k, -1);
    cg = circshift(gamma, -1);
    cx = circshift(x, -1);
    ccx =circshift(x, 1);

    d1 = -3 .* ck .* cg .* cx .^ 2 - ck;
    d2 = (k .* gamma + ck .* cg) .* x .^ 2 + k + ck;
    d3 = -3 .* k .* ccx .^ 2 - k;

    out = full(spdiags([d1 d2 d3], -1:1, N, N));
end
```

Comment: This is a beautiful implementation. I now see what you mean by named and anonymous functions @CrisLuengo

Comment: Why do you append 0 to x here with ```x = [x(1:N); 0]```? Why don't you just do ```x = x(1:N)```?

Comment: I think a zero is appended to `x` to make its length the same as the length of `k`.